# Python regex to remove whole word if there is any punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying this unsuccessfully for the past 2 days and it is driving me insane. I am trying to remove any whole word in python if it is connected to some sort of punctuation.

I have tried using \w but unfortunately that includes _. I am also trying to keep words with hyphens.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

An example would be:

Input:
(black re-d whit.e yellow, blue[p].o orange) green

Output:
re-d green

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: Is punctuation after the word okay or not such as `but, I am so tired.`  Should 'but' and/or 'tired' be removed or not due to the comma and period, respectively?

Comment: @DarrylG Yeah, the word should be removed if punctuation comes  after it. The result of the above should be 'I am so'. Also, I am looking for a way to also keep words with hyphens.

Comment: @maestromusica I added an example. Thanks!

Comment: In your example, why is re-ed okay considering it contains '-'?  Is only only bad to have punctuation at the beginning and end of the word?  So with `horse’s picture` is horse's and picture both okay?

Comment: @DarrylG Sorry for re-editing about the hyphen, I just came upon the realization that I would like to keep hyphenated words, but nothing else. In the above example, picture is ok but horse is not because it has the apostrophe. Thanks!

Comment: @mw99--thanks for the reply.  Could you check to see if my posted answer matches your criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the code below:

```
import re
s = "See ,remove .these words from the original string or? !not"
s = re.sub(r'\s+\w+\b\S', '', s) # Matches words that end with punctuation.
s = re.sub(r'\s+\S\b\w+', '', s) # Matches words that start with punctuation.
print(s)
```

When run, it outputs:

```
See words from the original string
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Unfortunately this does not seem to get rid of words that have some sort of punctuation before the first character, such as '(word'

Comment: @mw99 I just updated my answer, see if it works for you now. Alternatively we could make some more changes.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

`\w+\b\S`

\w+\b gets all whole words, then \S will limit those whole words to whole words that are followed by a non-whitespace character. Another, perhaps more explicit solution could look like this: `\w+\b[,.?!]`, with any punctuation you want to match in the brackets.

As a side note, I highly endorse [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) for any and all regex needs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming words followed by punctuation are not to be removed and one is not concerned by extra spaces left in the resulting string after words are removed, one could use the following regex:

```
\S*[.,:;!?-]\S*[^\s\.,:;!?-]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqlbSL/3/)

The regex tokens are as follows:

```
\S*            # match 0+ chars other than whitespace
[.,:;!?-]      # match a punctuation char
\S*            # match 0+ chars other than whitespace
[^\s\.,:;!?-]  # match a char other than a whitespace or a punctuation char
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
import re

def get_words(s):
  pattern = r'(?:^|(?<=\s))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?:$|(?=\s))'
  return ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

**Explanation**

```
(?:^|(?<=\s)) - matches beginning of word or space
(?:$|(?=\s)) - matches end of string or space
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ - one or more letters or numbers
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)? - matches letters/numbers and optionally followed
                                 by hypen followed by letters and numbers
                                 (so only accepts single hyphens between letters or numbers)
```

**Test Code**

```
s1 = "(black re-d whit.e yellow, blue[p].o orange) green"
s2 = "but, I am so tired."
s3 = "in the years 1902-1905 or was it 1904, or 1905"
s4 = """And underneath the guy on the horse’s picture, it always says: ‘Since 1888 we have been molding boys into splendid, clear-thinking young men."""

for i, s in enumerate([s1, s2, s3, s4]):
  print(f'Test {i}: {s}\nOutput:{get_words(s)}\n')
```

**Result**

Test 0: (black re-d whit.e yellow, blue[p].o orange) green

> Output:re-d green

Test 1: but, I am so tired.

> Output:I am so

Test 2: in the years 1902-1905 or was it 1904, or 1905

> Output: in the years 1902-1905 or was it or 1905

Test 3: And underneath the guy on the horse’s picture, it always says: ‘Since 1888 we have been molding boys into splendid, clear-thinking young men.

> Output: And underneath the guy on the it always 1888 we have been
>   molding boys into clear-thinking young